# How to do form validation using HTML and jQuery without redirecting to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have written a HTML form and script to validate the form. The issue is that whenever I go to submit the form I get redirected to a page that tells me "Your file was not found".

Is there a specific way I have to call the script? or any way I can force it to run without redirecting me?

```
<form id="bioform" action="/action_page.php">
  <label>Biography</label><br>
  <textarea placeholder="Enter bio here" name="bio" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
  <label>Update Biography Picture</label><br><br>
  <input type="file" name="bioimage"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="function()">Update</button><br>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bioform').validate({
        rules: {
          bio {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
          },
        }
        messages: {
          bio {
            required: 'Please enter a biography.',
            minlength: 'Please enter a valid biography.',
          },
        }
        });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" to form tag

```
    <form id="bioform" action="/action_page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label>Biography</label><br>
     <textarea placeholder="Enter bio here" name="bio" rows="10" cols="50">
     </textarea><br><br>
     <label>Update Biography Picture</label><br><br>
     <input type="file" name="bioimage"><br><br>
     <button type="submit" onclick="function()">Update</button><br>
    </form>
```

Comment: That seems to make no difference. Would I have to create a file called action_page.php in my directory? I was assuming it would be created automatically.

Comment: you didn't create the file action_page.php in your directory ? so where did you get the posted values ??

Comment: The user is supposed to enter the values on the webpage

Comment: if you don't want to create file in your directory remove action attiribute from from tag the values will posted on same page and you can place script as well on the same page ...

Answer (score 0):

Is the forward slash when specifying where it sends to necessary? For instance:

```
<form id="bioform" action="/action_page.php">
```

Should be replaced with:

```
<form id="bioform" action="action_page.php">
```

Comment: Removing the slash does not change it. I still get redirected. Would I have to create a file called action_page.php in my directory? I was assuming it would be created automatically.

Comment: Yes, you do have to create the file in the same directory as it is not done automatically.

Comment: Also, the PHP file is supposed to handle the data, not store it.

Comment: So would I put my script into the PHP file?

Comment: You would put a PHP script in the file to handle the information. You can get a tutorial at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, try using this:

`e.preventDefault()`

> The `e.preventDefault()` method stops the default action of an
>   element from happening. For example: Prevent a submit button from
>   submitting a form. Prevent a link from following the URL.

Also, you need to add `method` attribute inside the `<form>` tag with value `POST` and also the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` since you're dealing with file upload.

Go to this fiddle and check if it works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/z0db4vq0/1/